# Bulk and batching between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express without stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I want to use MS Sync Framework v2.1 to sync from a SQL Server 2008 to a SQL Server 2008 Express client. The server could have up to a few hundred thousand new rows while the client is turned off.  Because of the large number of possible rows, I want to implement batching and bulk imports.

Does anyone have ideas how to handle this situation of syncing down an unknown (a couple rows to a large amount of rows) from the server to the client?

One requirement that makes this harder is that the server cannot have stored procedures running on it, so I think that prohibits use of `SyncOrchestrator/SqlSyncProvider` unless the client can use the `SqlSyncProvider` and the server use another provider which does not require stored procedures?

I tried this approach, using `SyncOrchestrator/SqlSyncProvider` for the Local provider, and the `DbServerProvider` for the `RemoteProvider` but received an `InvalidCastException`. Is this possible?

Are there better options considering the restraint of not using stored procedures on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the DBServerProvider is an older provider that works differently. you used it with SyncAgent/SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DbServerSyncProvider combo. these providers are "anchor-based".

SyncOrchestrator/SqlSyncProvider/SqlCeSyncProvider combo is the newer one and is "knowledge-based".

the older DbServerProvider OOTB supports only SQL Compact for the client database. there used to be a SQLExpressClientSyncProvider but MS has already pulled it out from the download site.

there are ways to get away with not using stored procedures for the SqlSyncProvider by building the SQLCommands yourself in code. you would still need the triggers and tracking tables to track the changes though.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any comparison of the performance between using OOTB SqlSyncProvider with batching/bulk inserts vs SqlExpressClientsyncProvider (using the DbServerProvider with modifications) and SQL Change Tracking.  The reason for going change tracking route is because it is assumed the massive inserts into the server would cause large performance problems with triggers vs the internal change tracking table.  Is this true?

Comment: have a look at this discussion and the reply from MS around SQL CT: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synclab/thread/2ea93e2e-58f8-4847-85e6-c43a13a09a20